# OpenGL 1.1 Issue on Galaxy S/ Samsung Vibrant

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-1.1

I am trying to display two OpenGL surface views on the Samsung Vibrant/Galaxy S at once using OpenGL 1.1.  The device refuses to display both at once but doesn't throw any errors.  On all other devices I have tested this has worked.

Is this possibly an issue with Android 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading device to Android 2.2 fixed issues.  Not sure why though, maybe update fixed a bug as well?